What LinkedIn API returns data for the.Campaign Manager - Plan/Audiences (Company Engagement Report)?
I want to use the LinkedIn API to retrieve the data from the Company Engagement Report:

(Report Uri:
https://www.linkedin.com/campaignmanager/accounts/[account-id]/audiences/matched/[audience-id]/matched-companies)
What API endpoint has such information? I could not find any in the documentation.
I am interested in the Engagement level, Members targeted and Impressions columns.
EDIT: Important - I would like to filter by start and end date (the report has a fixed 90-day range). I would also like to filter by account, campaign group, campaign, and ad -- if possible.
Thanks

I gave up searching the doc and waiting for help from LinkedIn developers support. I just called the analytics API and computed the data by hand. The results are similar, but not identical to the engagement report, however.
This is the endpoint I am calling:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&dateRange=(start:(day:{start_day},month:{start_month},year:{start_year}),end:(day:{end_day},month:{end_month},year:{end_year}))&timeGranularity=(value:ALL)&accounts=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A{account_id})&fields={','.join(fields)}
